# Extract the minutes part of a time string

Tags: c#, trim

How can I trim all the colons and the hour and the seconds from a time string? I want to get the only total minutes from `00:15:27` (15). can you help me guys? My code only trims one of the colons how can I trim all colons and remove the seconds to get the minutes?

[image]

```
string s = label11.Text = "00:15:27";
s= label11.Text.Trim(':','0');
```

Comment: Use of `string.split` is the answer

Comment: `var s = label11.Text.split(':')[1]+":"+label11.Text.split(':')[2];`....?

Comment: Use `string[] time = label11.Text.Split(':')` and then `time[1]` to get the minute part, or easier to use `DateTime.Parse` and then get `Minutes` property from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why not just convert your string to time and get the minutes you want .. like this

```
  string s =  "00:15:27";
  DateTime Time = DateTime.ParseExact(s, "HH:mm:ss",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
  var minutes = s.Minute;
```

you will have your minutes .

For hours like you said in comments

```
var hours = s.Hour;
hoursTominutes = hours * 60 ;
var Totalminutes = hoursTominutes + minutes ;
```

Comment: thank you sir but how about the 01:15:27 then the 1 hour converted to 60mins so the total is 75 ? what can i do sir ?

Comment: you can get the hours as `s.Hour` as well and to continue this approach check for the number of hours e.g. 1,2,3 then multiple them with 60 and then add them in your minutes .

Comment: example if he late 1 hour up in her class  so i declare if statement ?

Comment: @Strudops i have edited my answer the way you said .

Comment: if(time >  "01:15:27"){
DateTime Time = DateTime.ParseExact(s, "HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            var minutes = Time.Minute;
            var minutes= Time.Hours:
then add ?
}

Comment: You have the total minutes now .. if you want to check for the value just simply substract your total minutes from your declared time .

Answer (score 0):

Its look like you are trying to get minute component from your string so it's better to parse your string to `TimeSpan` and then retrieve its minute component like,

```
string s = "00:15:27";

int minute = 0;
TimeSpan ts;

if (TimeSpan.TryParse(s, out ts))
{
    minute = ts.Minutes;
}
else
{
    //Your string is not in proper time format
}

Console.WriteLine("Minute:" + minute);
Console.ReadLine();
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Edit:**

If you want to get an hour, minute, and seconds component from your string then

```
string s = "01:15:27";

int hours = 0;
int minutes = 0;
int seconds = 0;
TimeSpan ts;

if (TimeSpan.TryParse(s, out ts))
{
    hours = ts.Hours;
    minutes = ts.Minutes;
    seconds = ts.Seconds;
}
else
{
    //Your string is not in time format
}

Console.WriteLine("Hours:" + hours);
Console.WriteLine("Minutes:" + minutes);
Console.WriteLine("Seconds:" + seconds);
Console.ReadLine();
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: sir how about the 01:15:27 time ? how can i convert to minute the 1 hour ?

Comment: means you want to get hour component and that is `01` in you case?

Comment: @Strudops, answer update see **Edit** section :)

Comment: @Strudops, you want to get like this => `01 Hour + 15 Minutes + 27 Seconds = 75.45 Minutes`?

Comment: yeah bro i get the logics from you and other helped to me hehhehehe thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

I Agree with Haroon nasir that parsing to a timespan is the way to go.

There is, however, an easier way to get the total amount of minutes: TimeSpan has the "TotalMinutes" property in it.

```
TimeSpan.Parse(timeAsString, out Timespan parsedTime);
double minutes = parsedTime.TotalMinutes;
```

using this for 1:15:27 will result 75.45 minutes without any extra steps

Comment: why with .45 bro? @thisIsme is that a seconds ?

Comment: @Strudrops, this is because that command gives fractional minutes. 27 seconds is 0.45 minutes

Note the difference between 75:45 and 75.45 minutes. the former is minutes:seconds, the latter is a fractional amount of minutes